# Can jQuery confuse an id with a variable?

Tags: jquery, html

I had a javascript variable "foo" and a span tag id named "foo" as well. For some reason jQuery seemed like it was confusing the variable for the id if the variable hasn't been declared. So if I wrote the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>jQuery Test</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Test">

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script>
      var foo = 100;
  </script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <span id="foo">200</span>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <p id="test">Foo Value</p>

    <script>
        $("#test").html(foo);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The html content of #foo gets selected. Is this a feature of jQuery or a bug or just another reason to follow the "DRY" rule?

Comment: Please read up on scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript. And, you are mixing up jQuery with (vanilla) Javascript - this is solely within the scope of Javascript :) As a hint: I've used to prefix my variables w/ `$` to avoid any overriding of global identifiers (which are within the `window` scope), like `$foo = $('#foo')`

Comment: This isn't a jQuery behaviour but a JS one. By default references to elements with `id` attributes get created as properties of the `window` object - the same as a global variable.

Comment: This also has nothing to do with DRY.